# "I'm having trouble with my Django 'delete' function in customer registration. It doesn't delete as expected. Can you review and advise? Thanks!"

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

"I'm working on a Django project for customer registration, and I'm encountering an issue with the 'delete' function. When I try to delete a customer's information, it doesn't work as expected. Can someone please review my 'delete' function and suggest any corrections or improvements? Thank you!"

This my view.py code block.

```
from . models import Customer
from django.contrib import messages

def cutomer_registration (request):
    message = ''
    data = ''
    number = 0
    
    if 'ok' in request.POST:
        name = request.POST['name'],
        surname = request.POST['surname'],
        email = request.POST['email'],
        phone = request.POST['phone']

        if name and surname and email and phone:
            if Customer.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email']).exists():
                message = "This email already exists."
            elif Customer.objects.filter(phone=request.POST['phone']).exists():
                message = "This phone already exists"
            else:
                save_data = Customer(
                    name = request.POST['name'],
                    surname = request.POST['surname'],
                    email = request.POST['email'],
                    phone = request.POST['phone '],
                    note = request.POST['note']
                )
                save_data.save()
                message = "Customer registration was successful."
        else:
            message = "Fill in the appropriate boxes"
    data = Customer.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    number = Customer.objects.count
    return render(request, 'registration_m.html', {'message' : message, 'data' : data, 'number' : number})

def del(request, id):
    if 'delete' in request.POST:
        customer = Customer.objects.get(id=id)
        if 'yes' in request.POST:
            customer.delete()
        else:
            return redirect('registration')
    return render(request, 'registration_m.html', {'customer' : customer})
```

This my html code block.

```
<h2>Customer Registration</h2>


<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="ad"><br>
    Surname:<br>
    <input type="text" name="soyad"><br>
    Phone:<br>
    <input type="tel" name="telefon"><br>
    E-mail:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    Note:<br>
    <textarea cols="20" rows="5" name="note"></textarea><br><br>
    <button name="ok">Qeyddiyyat</button>
</form>

{% if message %}
    {{message}}
    <br><br>
{% endif %}

{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {{message}}
    {% endfor %}
    <br><br>
{% endif %}

{% if number > 0 %}
    There is <b>{{number}}</b> customer in base.<br><br>
{% endif %}


<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for info in data %}
    #{{forloop.counter}}<br>
        <b>Customer:</b> {{info.name}} {{info.surname}}<br>
        <b>Phone:</b> {{info.phone}}<br>
        <b>E-mail:</b> {{info.email}}<br>
        <a href="{% url 'delete' info.id %}"><button>delete</button></a>

        {% if delete == info.id %}
            <br><br>
            Do you want to delete ID:{{info.id}}?
            <br><br>
            <button name="yes">Yes</button>
            <button name="no">No</button>
            <br><br>
        {% endif %}
        <br><br>
    {% endfor %}    
</form>
```

I'm trying to delete a customer using its ID and then asking on the same page a yes or no question for deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the link in the [**`action="…"`** <sup>[mdn]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attributes_for_form_submission) attribute of the form:

```
{% for info in data %}
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'delete' info.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <b>Customer:</b> {{info.name}} {{info.surname}}<br>
        <b>Phone:</b> {{info.phone}}<br>
        <b>E-mail:</b> {{info.email}}<br>
        <button type="submit">delete</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```